# Добрый день, нужна помощь в разбивки массива в js

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```js
let = ['dgdhdn,fbbxn,fhhd,djj','ddgh','xbbx']
```

его нужно разбить ввиде

```
dgdhdn
fbbxn
fhhd
djj
ddgh
xbbx
```

Как это можно осуществить.

Comment: Например с помощью for + split + splice

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, если я правильно понял Вашу задачу, можно сначала соединить с помощью `join` все отдельные элементы массива в один строковый, используя запятую между ними, а потом по той же запятой разделить эту строку на отдельные элементы с помощью `split`.

Полученный массив необходимых Вам строковых значений через цикл можно, к примеру, вывести в консоль или что там Вам нужно.

```
let arr = ['dgdhdn,fbbxn,fhhd,djj','ddgh','xbbx'];

let result = arr.join(',').split(',');

for (let item of result) {
    console.log(item);
}
```